# Is it safe to store .ppk files securely in S3 - use of S3, Java and ssh

Tags: java, security, encryption, amazon-s3, ssh

Part of the application I'm working connects to an instance using ssh.  It requires a .ppk file which I've currently got stored in S3.

My concern is that it's not secure enough and I'm looking for a method in which to make it so.

I've considered encrypting the S3 bucket and allowing programmatic access only, the bucket and file location can be fed to app via env variables.

I really don't want to keep the file in the resources as anyone getting the  jar cam unzip and obtain, same with hardcoded values in the codebase.  Is this a safe way of storing this file?  Would encrypting it be worth the additional steps?

Comment: Did you provide a password to the ppk file (assuming you mean Putty Private Key)?

Comment: @kennytm - yes this is a putty key, it's the one that's generated by Amazon when you're asking to cnnect to an instance, in this case I 'think' I've taken the .pem and made it a .ppk.  I haven't provided a password but I imagine this will have happened at some stage in order to generate it